# Why do laundry detergents go bad?

Tags: solutions

Common lore on the internet is that liquid laundry detergents go bad 1-2 years after they are purchased. Is this true? I'd like to understand the chemistry behind this. [This](https://smartlabel.pg.com/00037000856542.html) is the laundry detergent I am researching for o-chem.

Comment: A year or two? Mine gets exhausted long before then.

Comment: Hanging out with the wrong crowd will do it.

Answer (score 2):

"Common lore" is not exactly evidence. Can you cite anything to back that up the lifetime of laundry detergents? What happens after that time -- are they no longer effective?

That said, many laundry (and dishwasher) detergents now contain enzymes, e.g., [fungal alkaline proteases](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fmicb.2023.1138401/full), to break down protein-containing dirt and stains(foods, blood, etc.). Since proteases are enzymes that break down proteins (cleavage),and since these enzymes are *themselves* proteins, they might shred themselves over time. [In organisms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proteolysis), "Proteases... are synthesized in the *inactive* form so that they may be safely stored in cells... " [Postponing self-cleavage](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/acs.jafc.3c01618) could extend the shelf life of proteases.

Perhaps laundry detergents contain inhibitors to extend shelf life; some companies use [dry granules](https://biosolutions.novozymes.com/en/dish/insights/article/beginners-guide-enzymes-detergents) for that purpose. Others are [designing proteases](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-021-84267-w) more resistant to self-cleavage.

However, I've *not* noticed a difference in cleaning effect with old detergent; perhaps the issue of self-cleavage has been effectively ameliorated.